# Android Maps Utility: images from URL

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using the excellent [Android Maps Utility library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/) to display on the map custom markers withs clusters. It works great and it is very easy to customize.

My problem is how to change local resources from the demo (R.drawable.image_demo) to images from a URL. I'm using Universal Image Loader to load this images on the imageView async, but the problems is that the images are not loaded on the marker that corresponds.

Anyone know about any example?

This is the code where the image is downloaded and loaded inside the DefaultClusterRender class. Thanks in advance.

```
        @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MapFoto mapFoto, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        // Draw a single person.
        // Set the info window to show their name.
        // mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.barcelona);
        // mImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        Log.d("", "--- url: " + mapFoto.getPictureUrl());
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(mapFoto.getPictureUrl(), mImageView, BlipointApp.optionsAvatarImage, new ImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
                mImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
            }
        });

        Bitmap icon = mIconGenerator.makeIcon();
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon)).title(mapFoto.getName());
    }
```

Comment: You will have to download the image store it some where and then display. Do you use UIL?

Comment: Yes I'm using UIL. UIL stores and do the images cache, so I will not be worried about this. The problem is that the image view where the image is loaded is no the correct image view. But the image downloads and loads fine! mImageView.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);

Comment: I have the same problem, How do you solved it? Thank you

Comment: For the moment, first I pre-download the image bitmaps, then fill the mCluster with all the data downloaded, works perfectly like the demo. With this workflow I am not using the UIL. This a acceptable for a static markers and not many.

Comment: +Pelanes - Working on the same issue...  Want to leverage UIL as our images are stored on a backend database server and I don't want to download a bunch of thumbnails to the device (bunch as in 1000+ - its for an art museum gallery, no worries they won't all be shown on the map at the same time!). If you find a solution, I'd be interested - going to work on one from my end as well.

Comment: +Kyle if you find a solution with UIL or other library, please share with us :) I will try in the future with other libraries like https://github.com/koush/ion

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem using the UIL, not all images were loaded. Every time I ran the map activity and zoomed into the clusters there were different markers/clusters that had no image. Only the standard marker/cluster icons were shown.

Finally after two days of trying and trying it works fine. Temporarily I had switched to the Picasso library to see if it might work but I experienced similar problems there and couldn't get it done. Besides with Picasso all the images loaded from the web (URL) were rotated by 90 degrees. I couldn't figure out why. According to some posts that I found in the web it might have to do something with the device, I am using Samsung Galaxy S5 device for testing. But not sure....

Here some notes how I did it: I created a `HardRefSimpleImageLoadingListener` with an ImageView which will exist until UIL loading process is finished. Without its hard reference `ImageView` the onLoadingCancelled would get called and loading would not complete. I also created the objects `ClusterMarkerTarget` and `ClusterItemMarkerTarget` which contain a Marker, ImageView, and bitmap  for the Icon generators. I also put them into HashSets `myClusterItemMarkerTargets` and `myClusterMarkerTargets` to keep them from getting garbagecollected.

Maybe it can be of use for somebody.

Here some code:

```
        @Override
        protected void onClusterItemRendered(ReportItem clusterItem, Marker marker) {

        final ClusterItemMarkerTarget pm_ClusterItem = new ClusterItemMarkerTarget(marker);

        myClusterItemMarkerTargets.add(pm_ClusterItem);

        HardRefSimpleImageLoadingListener loadingListener = new HardRefSimpleImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String s, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                myClusterItemMarkerTargets.remove(pm_ClusterItem);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String s, View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
                mClusterItemImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                pm_ClusterItem.myIcon_cluster = mClusterItemIconGenerator.makeIcon();
                pm_ClusterItem.mMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(pm_ClusterItem.myIcon_cluster));
                myClusterItemMarkerTargets.remove(pm_ClusterItem);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String s, View view) {
                myClusterItemMarkerTargets.remove(pm_ClusterItem);
            }
        };

        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(clusterItem.picPath, pm_ClusterItem.myClusterItemImageView ,   loadingListener );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClusterRendered(Cluster<ReportItem> cluster, Marker marker) {

        int i=0;
        clustersize = cluster.getSize();

        final ClusterMarkerTarget pm_Cluster = new ClusterMarkerTarget(marker, cluster);

        myClusterMarkerTargets.add(pm_Cluster);

        for (ReportItem r : cluster.getItems()) {
            // Draw 1 at most.
            if (i == 1 ) {
                break;
            }

            HardRefSimpleImageLoadingListener loadingListener = new HardRefSimpleImageLoadingListener() {

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String s, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                    myClusterMarkerTargets.remove(pm_Cluster);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String s, View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    mClusterImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); // = (ImageView) view; //pm.myClusterImageView;
                    pm_Cluster.myIcon_clusterItem = mClusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(String.valueOf(clustersize));
                    pm_Cluster.myMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(pm_Cluster.myIcon_clusterItem));
                    myClusterMarkerTargets.remove(pm_Cluster);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String s, View view) {
                    myClusterMarkerTargets.remove(pm_Cluster);
                }
            };

            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(r.picPath, pm_Cluster.myClusterImageView, loadingListener);

            i++;
        }
    }
```

more:

```
//Set for holding a reference to marker targets --> targets won't get carbage collected during looping and loading images
Set<ReportRenderer.ClusterItemMarkerTarget> myClusterItemMarkerTargets = new HashSet<>();
Set<ReportRenderer.ClusterMarkerTarget>     myClusterMarkerTargets  = new HashSet<>();
```

more:

```
public ReportRenderer(ClusterManager<ReportItem> mClusterManager, GoogleMap map) {

        super(MyApplication.getContext(), map, mClusterManager);

        mDimension  = (int) MyApplication.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.custom_report_image);
        mPadding    = (int) MyApplication.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.custom_report_padding);

        // initialize cluster icon generator
        View multiReport = inflater.inflate(R.layout.multi_report, null);
        mClusterImageView = (ImageView) multiReport.findViewById(R.id.image_report);
        mClusterIconGenerator = new IconGenerator(MyApplication.getContext());
        mClusterIconGenerator.setContentView(multiReport);

        // initialize cluster item icon generator
        mClusterItemImageView = new ImageView(MyApplication.getContext());
        mClusterItemImageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(mDimension, mDimension));
        mClusterItemImageView.setPadding(mPadding, mPadding, mPadding, mPadding);
        mClusterItemIconGenerator = new IconGenerator(MyApplication.getContext());
        mClusterItemIconGenerator.setContentView(mClusterItemImageView);

        // initialize image loader
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.loading)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.warning)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.fail)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                        //.bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .build();
        config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(MyApplication.getContext())
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
                .build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    }
```

more:

```
//cluster marker with image loaded by Ultimate Image Loader
    class ClusterMarkerTarget {

        Marker    myMarker;
        ImageView myClusterImageView;

        public ClusterMarkerTarget(Marker marker, Cluster<ReportItem> cluster) {
            myMarker = marker;
            View multiReport = inflater.inflate(R.layout.multi_report, null);
            myClusterImageView = (ImageView) multiReport.findViewById(R.id.image_report);
        }
    }

    //cluster item marker with image loaded by Ultimate Image Loader
    class ClusterItemMarkerTarget {

        Marker      mMarker;
        ImageView   myClusterItemImageView;

        public ClusterItemMarkerTarget(Marker marker) {
            mMarker = marker;
            myClusterItemImageView =  new ImageView(MyApplication.getContext());//mClusterItemImageView;
            myClusterItemImageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(mDimension, mDimension));
            int padding = (int) MyApplication.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.custom_report_padding);
            myClusterItemImageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        }
    }
```

and finally:

```
 class HardRefSimpleImageLoadingListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {
        public ImageView mView;

        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            mView = (ImageView) view;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will keep your code for the next project with GoogleMapsUtil :)

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. Btw, Is there any way to make it work with Picasso?

Comment: @franco-phong I am glad that it works with your app. I am sure there is a way to make it work with Picasso, but after one week (!) trying I gave up and switched to UIL.

Comment: Thank you so much bro. It works for me. Have you found out to do the same with Picasso ? If yes, please post that code too... I really need it...